# Angular get promise data before directive link execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working on a directive that needs some information to work. But that information comes from a promise and the directive loads without that information because it takes more time that the directive itself.

```
angular.module('app').directive('tagInput', tagInput);

var tagInput = function ($timeout, profileService) {

  var profileList = profileService.getProfileList();

  profileList.then(function (profiles) {
    var profileObject = {};
    var profilesFiltered = [];

    for(var index in profiles){
      if(profiles[index].hasOwnProperty('id')){
        var notStandard = profiles[index].id.match(/\d+/g);
        if (notStandard != null) {
          profileObject.icon = '<i class="fa fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
        }
        else{
          profileObject.icon = '<i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
        }
        profileObject.name = profiles[index].name;
        profileObject.identifier = profiles[index].id;
        profileObject.ticked = false;
        profilesFiltered.push(profileObject);
      }
    }

    return profilesFiltered;
  });

return {
  restrict: 'EA',
  require: 'ngModel',
  scope: {
    tags: '=ngModel',
    searchParams: '=searchParams'
  },
  replace: false,
  link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {

    scope.modelFilter = {
      showSearchPanel: false,
      inputProfiles: profilesFiltered,

...
```

In this way always the data in the template appears empty. How can I prepare the data before the directive link execution. Maybe I will need a similar promise to `inputAccounts: accountsFiltered,`.

Answer (score 0):

First you can't do a dependency between the render of a directive and a promise, there is a way but this is an antipattern. You need another point of view.

For example if you want that `scope.modelFilter` fills only when the promise ends you can make a watcher inside the link function of the directive. Watch the profiles filtered field and inside the callback fill the `modelFilter`.